# MSSQL to MySQL - "Invalid date literal detected" when reading decimal

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date, decimal, database-migration

I'm attempting a migration from MSSQL to MySQL and keep coming across a "Invalid date literal detected" error when reading certain decimal columns. I'm running the following (all up-to-date as of posting):

```
Windows 7
MSSQL 2008 R2 
MySQL 5.6.21 Community 
Workbench 6.2.3
```

I've attempted to re-run the migration a number of times with the same rows/tables causing the same issues. For instance with the following 'Times' table:

```
INSERT INTO `GenshenHR2`.`Times` (`TimesID`, `TimesheetID`, `StaffID`, `StoreID`, `JobID`, `Hours`, `Holiday`, `Overtime`, `Unpaid`) 
VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,'97.0','.0','.0','.0'),(2,1,2,1,2,'152','.0','.0','.0'),
(3,1,3,1,3,'152','.0','.0','.0'),(4,1,4,1,4,'152','.0','.0','.0'),
(5,6,5,6,6,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(6,6,8,6,9,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(7,6,9,6,10,'80.0','8.0','8.0','.0'),(8,6,10,6,11,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(9,6,11,6,12,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(10,6,12,6,13,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(11,6,13,6,14,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(12,6,14,6,15,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(13,6,15,6,16,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(14,6,16,6,17,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(15,6,17,6,18,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(16,6,18,6,19,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(17,6,19,6,20,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(18,6,20,6,21,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(19,6,21,6,22,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(20,6,22,6,23,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(21,6,23,6,24,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(22,6,24,6,25,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(23,6,25,6,26,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(24,6,26,6,27,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(25,6,27,6,28,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(26,6,28,6,29,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(27,6,29,6,30,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(28,2,30,2,31,'177','8.0','.0','.0'),
(29,2,31,2,32,'179','4.0','.0','.0'),(30,2,32,2,33,'179','8.0','.0','.0'),
(31,2,33,2,34,'177','4.0','.0','.0'),(32,2,34,2,35,'177','.0','.0','.0'),
(33,2,35,2,36,'24.0','.0','.0','.0'),(34,2,36,2,37,'177\0\0','.0','.0','.0'),
(35,2,37,2,38,'64.5','.0','.0','.0'),(36,2,38,2,39,'114\0\0','.0','57.5','.0'),
(37,4,39,4,40,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(38,4,40,4,41,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(39,4,41,4,42,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(40,4,42,4,43,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(41,4,43,4,44,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(42,4,44,4,45,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(43,4,45,4,46,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(44,4,46,4,47,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(45,4,47,4,48,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(46,4,48,4,49,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(47,4,49,4,50,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(48,4,50,4,51,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(49,4,51,4,52,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(50,4,52,4,53,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(51,4,53,4,54,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(52,4,54,4,55,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(53,4,55,4,56,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),(54,4,56,4,59,'.0','.0','.0','.0'),
(55,4,57,4,60,'.0','.ERROR:`GenshenHR2`.`Times`:Inserting Data: Incorrect decimal value: '177' for column 'Hours' at row 34
```

For some reason it is interpreting the data in the 6th column 'Hours' with slashes (eg 177\0\0) on rows 34 & 36 instead of the correct decimal format (eg 177.5)

In MSSQL the column is: `[Hours] NUMERIC(4,1) NULL DEFAULT 0`
Its corresponding line in the Migration is: `'Hours' DECIMAL(4,1) NULL DEFAULT 0`

Ironically the following 3 columns (Holiday, Overtime & Unpaid) are all the same datatype, and looking at the log extract appear to insert without issue (see row 36 / 57.5).

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your string literal: `177\0\0`. In MySQL the backward slash is the escape character. SQL Server doesn't allow it, so it tried to convert `177\0\0` as literal string into a number. But why would you export a numeric field as a string literal during your migration?

Also, remove the back ticks (`` ` ``). SQL Server doesn't recognize them.

Comment: I'm not exporting a literal string, I don't understand how it appeared at all - in SQL Server that column is NUMERIC(4,1) and the data is clearly stored as 177.5.  To clarify I'm using the MySQL Workbench migration tool which is producing this error (it also included the back ticks itself). Is something in the migration tool causing this to happen?